# NetBeans 6.9, CMake and C++: How to specify the build path?

Tags: c++, netbeans, cmake

I prefer to have a separate build directory when working with CMake.
Can I tell NetBeans 6.9 to use that directory such that

```
CMakeCache.txt
```

etc. go there?

Answer (score 7):

This feature has been [integrated in Netbeans a few months ago](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=175374). When creating a project from existing sources, you must use the custom mode in order to obtain the possibility to specify the build directory.

You can also modify the output directory in the project properties, the `Build/Make` section.

Comment: Note that in an existing project you can change this setting by right-clicking the main CMakeLists.txt file and editing the "Run Directory".